# TeamCity Не происходит обработка переменной при попытке обращения к хранилищу Hashicorp Vault

Tags: teamcity

В своей конфигурации сборки TeamCity определяю набор переменных окружения, в которые будут заноситься секреты из Hashicorp Vault. У меня в проекте настроено несколько соединений (Connections) для разных серверов Hashicorp Vault, обращение к каждому из них происходит посредством поля Parameter namespace в настройках соединения. Чтобы не плодить кучу переменных на каждое из соединений, я решил использовать конфигурационный параметр *%envName%* и добавил его в переменную окружения, которая содержит строку для соединения с Hashicorp Vault следующим образом:

`%vault:%envName%:dir/%envName%!/secret_key%`

В данном примере первая переменная *%envName%* отвечает за выбор соединения в соответствии с Parameter namespace, а вторая указывает на каталог с секретами.

Однако, когда я запускаю сборку, то шаг Hashicorp Vault пропускается. Самое интересное то, что во втором случае с указателем на каталог переменная обрабатывается нормально. Также, когда я ввожу значение руками вместо первого *%envName%*, сборка тоже отрабатывает без проблем, а когда делаю наоборот - шаг снова пропускается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?